# Keep ERC buffers in the background on reconnect

Tags: buffers, erc

I'm using ERC (with ZNC) as my IRC client.  I'm joined to quite a few channels and when I run `znc-all` all my buffers are restored and the logs are replayed.  This is all great.

What I find very annoying, however, is that while replaying the logs each channel buffer is popped to the front and I really can't do any other work at that time.

It's even more annoying when I'm reconnecting automatically after being temporarily disconnected.  All of a sudden my work is interrupted by these channel buffers that pop to the front while the channel logs are replayed.

How can I tell ERC/ZNC to keep the buffers in the background when replaying chat logs?  I don't want Emacs to ever switch buffers unless I explicitly ask it to switch buffers.

Comment: What about using [dedicated window](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Dedicated-Windows.html#Dedicated-Windows)?

Comment: I don't want to dedicate any window to any of the many buffers I have open, just to prevent ERC from popping its own buffers.  I have never used dedicated windows, though.  Could you expand on how this can be used to stop ERC from popping buffers without having to mark each of the buffers I could possibly visit as dedicated?

Comment: "without having to mark each of the buffers I could possibly visit as dedicated"? No I can't, I was thinking about mark some windows as dedicated & when inside those windows, no other buffer will popup

Comment: I'm not sure I completely understand the question. Is it that the function znc-all sometimes runs automatically and takes you off whatever you're working on? Could you write a different function which runs automatically which doesn't switch the window?

Comment: I connect to ZNC on my server at the beginning of my session with `znc-all`.  After connecting, all channel buffers are replayed.  Emacs switches from buffer to buffer until the logs for each channel have been replayed.  This is (barely) acceptable behaviour when the session starts.  It's very annoying, however, when the ZNC connection was interrupted and Emacs reconnects automatically (how? I don't know).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
(setq erc-join-buffer 'bury)

erc-join-buffer is a variable defined in `erc.el'.
Its value is bury
PDocumentation:
Determines how to display a newly created IRC buffer.

The available choices are:

  'window          - in another window,
  'window-noselect - in another window, but don't select that one,
  'frame           - in another frame,
  'bury            - bury it in a new buffer,
  'buffer          - in place of the current buffer,
  any other value  - in place of the current buffer.
```

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly what I was looking for and could not find!

Comment: Won't this also bury query buffers? I'd see that as a problem, I wouldn't see new private conversations!

Comment: It does also bury query buffers, yes. I use `erc-track` though, so anytime someone queries me, I see a tiny letter in the modeline and hit my keybinding for `erc-track-switch-buffer` as soon as my colleague has stopped peeking over my shoulder. After a while I've come to prefer that over having a big window pop up full of private information.